# Why can you not call GetHashCode() on an interface reference in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Why won't this compile?

```
Public Interface IFoo
End Interface

Public Class Foo
    Shared Sub Bar(obj As IFoo)
        Dim i As Integer = obj.GetHashCode()
    End Sub
End Class
```

It is absolutely ridiculous that I'd have to do something like this

```
Shared Function ThisMakesNoSense(obj As Object) As Integer
    Return obj.GetHashCode()
End Function

Shared Sub Bar(obj As IFoo)
    Dim i As Integer = ThisMakesNoSense(obj)
End Sub
```

but that does compile.

Comment: What is the compiler error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compiles and runs fine for me; even after turning Option Strict On:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f2 As New Foo2
        Foo.Bar(f2)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Foo2
    Implements IFoo

End Class


Public Interface IFoo
End Interface

Public Class Foo

    Shared Sub Bar(obj As IFoo)
        Dim i As Integer = obj.GetHashCode()
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Can you give more details about your environment?

*I'm using VS Studio Community 2013.

**EDIT**

You could try casting "obj" to an Object before calling GetHashCode():

```
Public Class Foo

    Shared Sub Bar(obj As IFoo)
        Dim i As Integer = DirectCast(obj, Object).GetHashCode()
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It must just be because this is a legacy product. This is in VS 2005